# OpenGL-ES Android: function pointers esUtil.h

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, function-pointers, syntax-error

I am in a project on OpenGL in Linux FC16. We have been doing a lot of 3D and so far so good.

This month the company decided to port the whole system to OpenGL-ES.

I have installed the OpenGL ES as usual:

```
yum install make gcc mesa-libGLES-devel mesa-libEGL-devel
ref. http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/wiki/Instructions
```

On Eclipse IDE the ES was also included:

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C Linker > Libraries > Libraries (-l)+:
EGL
GLES
```

Trying to run the compiler, it gives the error:

```
../src/esUtil.h:84:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../src/esUtil.h:85:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../src/esUtil.h:86:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

which directs me to this:

```
/// Callbacks
void (ESCALLBACK *drawFunc) ( void* );
void (ESCALLBACK *keyFunc) ( void*, unsigned char, int, int );
void (ESCALLBACK *updateFunc) ( void*, float deltaTime );
ref. http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/source/browse/trunk/samples/gles2_book/Common/esUtil.h?r=486
```

I tried to put additional parenthesis, but it does not fixed it anyway. This is just driving me crazy.

Any suggestions or comments are highlight appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

At the top of esUtil.h try:

```
#define __cdecl
```

See if it builds. If it does then you have a problem with __cdecl being a windows definition that gcc does not support.

I think a fix will be:

```
#define __cdecl __attribute__((__cdecl__))
```

PS: Cdecl is a Visual C extension that is not supported by gcc (I think).

Comment: Thanks PAntoine. I tried your both suggestions. Then when I run the compiler the only message displayed is: make: "*** [src/ogl_es01.o] Error 1". While in the file esUtil.h the following warning appears: "‘__cdecl__’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]" for functions such as "void (ESCALLBACK *keyFunc) ( void*, unsigned char, int, int );". Any comments or suggestion?

Comment: I am surprised that the first one did not work. That simply removes the __cdecl from the definition. I have not use OpenGL on Android, but what do they do in the same header file? (have you got the NDK? - I assume you have).  Try removing the ESCALLBACK from the definition.